# What is the probability of at least one ace and at least one heart for two draws without replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have C(52,2) - C(48,2) - C(39,2) + C(36,2)/C(52,2). So, all the ways of drawing two cards from a deck of 52 minus all the ways of drawing an ace minus all the ways of drawing a heart plus all the ways of drawing neither an ace or heart, divided by all the ways of drawing two cards from a deck of 52. Is this correct? If not, why?

Comment: I think you need to consider the two cases of either drawing the ace of hearts or of drawing another ace and another heart.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and is a good example of how to use inclusion-exclusion properly, though your notation and typesetting could be improved.

$1 - \left(\dfrac{\binom{48}{2}+\binom{39}{2}-\binom{36}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}\right)=\dfrac{29}{442}$

This is, of course, the same answer as what is suggested in the comments above... drawing the ace of hearts and any other card in some order, or drawing a nonheart ace and a nonace heart in some order:

$\dfrac{2}{52} + 2\cdot\dfrac{12}{52}\cdot\dfrac{3}{51}=\dfrac{29}{442}$

Be warned that when typing math with ascii, a phrase like `a - b / c` or even worse `a - b/c` like you had is more commonly interpreted as $a - \frac{b}{c}$ where the $a$ is *not* a part of the fraction which is clearly not what you intended.  Further, the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ for binomial coefficients is preferable to $C(n,k)$ to avoid confusion with other functions (*at least in the west*).

Answer (score 1):

Although your attempt is correct after correcting typo, a direct approach  is simpler.

$\binom11\binom{51}1 = 51$ [ace of hearts and any other]

$\binom31\binom{12}1=36$ [non-heart ace and a non-ace hearts]

and $Pr = \Large\frac{87}{\binom{52}{2}}$

---

**ADDED**

It will be crystal clear if you look at the $4$ disjoint parts

- $12 \;\;{\heartsuit}$ **non** aces
- $1 \;\;\;\;{\heartsuit}$ ace
- $3 \;\;\;$ **non** ${\heartsuit}$ aces
- $36\;\;$ **non** ${\heartsuit}$ **non** aces